# Икеа или Икея?

Tags: орфография, заимствования

Взять, например, имя Мария, которое тут уже однажды обсуждалось. Латиницей это имя пишется Maria, но читаем ведь мы не Мариа, а Мария. Тогда почему везде пишут "Икеа", а не "Икея" (я принципиально пишу всегда "Икея"))) и "медиа", а не "медия"?
Мне кажется, что это не правильно. Мы ведь все равно произносим в конце "-ия", а не "-иа".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В википедии упоминается такой разговорный вариант произношения, но если речь идёт о аббревиатуре названия фирмы, то написание должно подчиняться общим принципам (в данном случае аббревиатура транслитерирована из англоязычной). Если же есть такое женское имя, то логично с ним поступить так же, как с "марией". С другой стороны, есть похожее имя Андреа (Andrea), которое в итальянском может быть мужским ("я" вряд ли подойдёт). Из английского имя с таким же написанием (обычно женское) лучше переводить по произношению (напр. Эндриа), которое сильно отличается от чтения в прямой транслитерации. В последнем случае имя читается легче с "а", в связи с расположением ударения (первый слог), отличным от "мария/лючия". Поэтому на мой взгляд, лучше с каждым случаем разбираться отдельно. Слова типа "аудио", "медиа" я заменяю на нормальные, подходящие по контексту, напр. "звук" и "пресса".

Answer (score 3):

Это сокращение, так же как и USA.
Название «IKEA» является акронимом, и расшифровывается как «Ingvar Kamprad Elmtaryd Agunnaryd», то есть имя и фамилия основателя и название фермы Эльмтарюд в приходе Агуннарюд, где он родился.

Этим все сказано.  ИКЕЯ -- народное творчество, так же как и уазик. Превращение торговой марки в удобоваримое для привычного произношения. Просто за это никто не накажет, а вот с Уся могут обидеться.

Answer (score 0):

Таблицы практической транскрипции с английского языка на русский Ермоловича (в данном случае английский или шведский язык - неважно), говорят нам о том, что правилом регулярной транскрипции является передача этой фонемы как "иа". "Мария" - исторически сложившееся написание, на него современные регулярные правила не распространяются.